# How to run copype.cmd for WinPE from Batch File

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, dism, winpe

I'm writing a tool that sets up a WinPE Drive for you, and I have been calling DISM commands from an admin batch file. However, I cannot figure out how to run the copype command to set up the drive initially.
 `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\copype.cmd"` is where the copype tool is located but when calling it with dism with this command: `Dism "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\copype.cmd" amd64 C:\WinPE_amd64` it responds that `Dism doesn't recognise the command-line option "copype.cmd"` If I try running the file directly from a command prompt, it says it cannot find the amd64 infrastructure. The only way I can get it to start is if I run an administrator Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment and run the copype command. There must be a way to do this, but I cant figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the Windows ADK Copype has been a bit broken since Windows 8. It's missing some variable. If you put this in your batch file you can use `call :copype` to call commands to it:

```
:copype
setlocal

set TEMPL=media
set FWFILES=fwfiles

rem
rem Input validation
rem
if /i "%1"=="/?" goto usage
if /i "%1"=="" goto usage
if /i "%~2"=="" goto usage
if /i not "%3"=="" goto usage

rem
rem Set environment variables for use in the script
rem
set WINPE_ARCH=%1
set SOURCE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\%WINPE_ARCH%
set FWFILESROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\%WINPE_ARCH%\Oscdimg
set DEST=%~2
set WIMSOURCEPATH=%SOURCE%\en-us\winpe.wim

rem
rem Validate input architecture
rem
rem If the source directory as per input architecture does not exist,
rem it means the architecture is not present
rem
if not exist "%SOURCE%" (
  echo ERROR: The following processor architecture was not found: %WINPE_ARCH%.
  exit /b 1
)

rem
rem Validate the boot app directory location
rem
rem If the input architecture is validated, this directory must exist
rem This check is only to be extra careful
rem
if not exist "%FWFILESROOT%" (
  echo ERROR: The following path for firmware files was not found: "%FWFILESROOT%".
  exit /b 1
)

rem
rem Make sure the appropriate winpe.wim is present
rem
if not exist "%WIMSOURCEPATH%" (
  echo ERROR: WinPE WIM file does not exist: "%WIMSOURCEPATH%".
  exit /b 1
)

rem
rem Make sure the destination directory does not exist
rem
if exist "%DEST%" (
  echo ERROR: Destination directory exists: %2.
  exit /b 1
)

mkdir "%DEST%"
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo ERROR: Unable to create destination: %2.
  exit /b 1
)

echo.
echo ===================================================
echo Creating Windows PE customization working directory
echo.
echo     %DEST%
echo ===================================================
echo.

mkdir "%DEST%\%TEMPL%"
if errorlevel 1 goto :FAIL
mkdir "%DEST%\mount"
if errorlevel 1 goto :FAIL
mkdir "%DEST%\%FWFILES%"
if errorlevel 1 goto :FAIL

rem
rem Copy the boot files and WinPE WIM to the destination location
rem
xcopy /cherky "%SOURCE%\Media" "%DEST%\%TEMPL%\"
if errorlevel 1 goto :FAIL
mkdir "%DEST%\%TEMPL%\sources"
if errorlevel 1 goto :FAIL
copy "%WIMSOURCEPATH%" "%DEST%\%TEMPL%\sources\boot.wim"
if errorlevel 1 goto :FAIL

rem
rem Copy the boot apps to enable ISO boot
rem
rem  UEFI boot uses efisys.bin
rem  BIOS boot uses etfsboot.com
rem
copy "%FWFILESROOT%\efisys.bin" "%DEST%\%FWFILES%"
if errorlevel 1 goto :FAIL
if exist "%FWFILESROOT%\etfsboot.com" (
  copy "%FWFILESROOT%\etfsboot.com" "%DEST%\%FWFILES%"
  if errorlevel 1 goto :FAIL
)

endlocal
echo.
echo Success
echo.

cd /d "%~2"

goto :EOF

:usage
echo Creates working directories for WinPE image customization and media creation.
echo.
echo copype { amd64 ^| x86 ^| arm } ^<workingDirectory^>
echo.
echo  amd64             Copies amd64 boot files and WIM to ^<workingDirectory^>\media.
echo  x86               Copies x86 boot files and WIM to ^<workingDirectory^>\media.
echo  arm               Copies arm boot files and WIM to ^<workingDirectory^>\media.
echo                    Note: ARM content may not be present in this ADK.
echo  workingDirectory  Creates the working directory at the specified location.
echo.
echo Example: copype amd64 C:\WinPE_amd64
goto :EOF

:FAIL
echo ERROR: Failed to create working directory.
set EROP=YEs
exit /b 1
Rem CopyPE created by Microsoft and Edited by Lucas Elliott and wjsorensen on technet
::------------------------ END --------------------------
```

For Anyone using Windows 8, you can see their solution here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1155d38c-e7fd-4b4f-a31c-26875d4f47a7/windows-pe-error-using-windows-8-adk?forum=w8itproinstall

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, I stepped here looking for info about copype, and followed the link to the technet forum. There's a new post from a few days ago - I strongly recommend reading it. In short, copype is not broken at all: it is just meant to be run from the ADK environment (the cmd prompt called by clicking the apposite link in Start -> All Programs -> Windows Kits -> Windows ADK). (Oh well, this is the path on Win 7: I installed the Windows 8 ADK (version 6.3.9600.17029) on Windows 7; in Win 8, and probably also in Win 10, the path will be somewhat different due to the different layout of the Start menu.)

Comment: Yeah on Windows 10 everything is different.